# Keystore password for Jetty 7.0 SSL configuration

Tags: ssl, jetty, keystore, keytool

Trying to setup SSL on jetty 7.2.2 using these instructions:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+configure+SSL

stuck on 3b:
`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore jetty.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore $JETTY_HOME/etc/keystore`

jetty ships with default keystore at `$JETTY_HOME/etc/keystore`. I'm asked for password when running that command. I don't know default keystore password.

If I try to replace that keystore with newly created one - I'm getting IOException on jetty startup - keystore is tampered with or password incorrect.

What I'm doing wrong? Or what's default keystore jetty password?

Comment: Hi, could you provide your jetty.xml file as an example? I'm following the same guide but cannot get it to work. The only thing I can think I'm doing wrong is not supplying the passwords correctly in step #4. I only have a jetty.xml file in my setup, no jetty-ssl.xml as you mentioned. Jetty is such a tease.

Comment: For me, the key password that ended up working was the one provided at the step where the pkcs12 file is created (ie. 3b). I was initially using the key password from the initial key creation. FYI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just want to overwrite the keystore in etc/keystore with your new one. Then, update the Jetty conf as in Step 4. You will need to obfuscate your keystore password using the `org.mortbay.jetty.security.Password` class.

Comment: done that, but got keystore is tampered problem. I'm assured I've provided right password in jetty.xml.

Comment: by the way - tried both - plain and obfuscated passwords in jetty.xml

Comment: Plain passwords worked for me. I will be obfuscating them when we move to production.

Answer (score 14):

The default password for the keystore that is shipped with jetty is `storepwd`.  But I would highly recommend you follow the steps listed in the [How to configure SSL](https://web.archive.org/web/20150530230420/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+configure+SSL) and create your own keystore.

Comment: And default key password for `<jetty>` is `keypwd`

Answer (score 2):

One more subtle steps that needs to be followed .

i.e Jetty has another file start.ini, un-comment jetty-ssl.xml line  to make the SSL configuration active.

Answer (score 0):

That was my bad. Didn't notice that there's jetty-ssl.xml also, that used default keystore. Moved addConnector to jetty-ssl.xml, put right passwords there, and everything works now like a charm.

Comment: You could also have used the `<Set name="keystoreType">PKCS12</Set>` to save you the trouble of converting your keystore.

Answer (score 0):

One note, the eclipse version of jetty works a little differently http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t88098.html

Answer (score 0):

Today with **jetty 9.4.34** and you'd like to use the default keystore password `storepwd` and default private key password `keypwd`, so that you don't have to modify the config, and you have cert/key in common **PEM** format...

```sh
tmpcert="/tmp/certkey$RANDOM.pkcs12" ; \
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey "key.pem" \
        -in "cert.pem" \
        -passout "pass:storepwd" \
        -out "$tmpcert" \
&& \
keytool -importkeystore \
        -srckeystore "$tmpcert" -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
        -srcstorepass storepwd \
        -destkeystore "$JETTY_BASE/etc/keystore" -deststoretype JKS \
        -deststorepass storepwd \
        -destkeypass keypwd ; \
rm "$tmpcert"
```

That's all you need to import to provide SSL functionality

Because of **JKS** there is the

> Warning: The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended
> to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using
> ...

**But** it is the only possibility to set a **different keypass** like `keypwd` for key and `storepwd` for keystore.
For **pkcs12** storetype this distinction is impossible (at least with keytool, there is an error on execution).

For the rest (like config modifications for own passwords, and generating own passwords) the documentation at https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html is ok.